# Horizontal Scrollview inside Scrollview

Tags: java, android, xml

I am stuck in Horizontal Scrollview inside the scroll view.

[image]

I can scroll horizontally (Child) but vertical scrolling (parent) isn't working.

Comment: Hello Pritam, welcome to SO. There is *no single* `?` question mark in your ... question... what is... the question? :) Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: please post your layout code.